# 20AWG wire inductor and 8A, possible?

Tags: inductor, wire, amperage

I have a inductor made up of ~5cm of 20AWG wire. Switching frequency of the inductor is 500kHz. And the duty cycle is somewhere between 10-30%. Maximum current through the inductor is 8A at around 13.5V.

I am wondering can this "relatively small" wire, take this amount of current? How could I calculate it out?

If it cant, will simply tying together more wires work? How many would I have to tie together?

**EDIT:**

Since it isn't possible, I am thinking of buying one. Would [this](http://si.farnell.com/epcos/b82111bc16/inductor-3uh-20-9a-220mhz/dp/9754113?ost=inductor&aa=true&min=110137860&categoryId=700000005470) be suitable? Its supposebly high-frequency rated for 9A.

Comment: What has an online current calculator told you?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Online calculator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not realistically.

AWG 20 would be marginal for 8A RMS (it's the RMS current that matters, not the peak) **even at DC**, however the maximum frequency for 100% skin depth on AWG 20 is in the low tens of kHz. 500kHz is way above that and the waveform your question implies will have substantial energy at higher harmonics like 1.5MHz. Google **Litz**(endraht). You'll probably end up with some dozens of AWG34 wires (in parallel). See [here](http://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm), for example.

Edit: [Skin effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect) is caused by eddy currents circulating **within** the wire. The current only goes so deep into the wire at high frequencies (it only flows through the skin), so the inner part of the wire is effectively doing nothing (it actually falls off exponentially rather than suddenly ceasing at some depth- we refer to the depth where it's fallen to 1/e \$\approx\$ 0.368 as the skin depth). So, as the wire diameter increases, the resistance only decreases proportionally to the diameter (the circumference) rather than the square of the diameter (cross sectional area) as you'd expect at DC.

The exact number of wire gauge(s) you need will depend on how hot your inductor will run (including self heating from copper and core losses as well as ambient) and what temperature your wire insulation is capable of. Allowable maximum resistance or power loss may also be concerns.

Comment: Wasn't aware there was an intrisic frequency limit to wires. What's the limiting effect? Inductance will skew square waves (meaning it limits the bandwidth attenuating harmonics), but you seem to say the wire itself has a limited frequency range.

Comment: @MisterMystère Practically there is no frequency limit. However as the frequency increase the effective cross section area of the wire decrease and a solid wire becomes a hollow cylinder. Consiquently current capacity decrease. see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect

Comment: @MisterMystère Please see edit above.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks, I've wondered forever what skin depth actually is. This is very educational.

Answer (score 2):

Even with DC current 8A is too much for this size of wire (current density 1,550A/cm^2). A current of 4A in AWG20, rising the temperature to 60degr Celcius in free air (curent density about 800A/cm2^). Now with a volume reduction more than half due to skin effect the temperature increase far beyond the insulation limit (assuming formvar). Thinks getting even worse because it is a coil and hot spot temperature will be more than the surface. In this case the use of a duty 30% does not help at all.

Don't go more than 300A/cm^2 for coils and transformers and 600A/cm^2 for house wiring.

Answer (score 1):

#20 AWG solid copper magnet wire has a resistance of 10.4 ohms per 1000 feet at 20C, which is about 341µ\$ \Omega\$ per centimeter, so a 5 centimeter length of that wire would have a resistance of about 1.7 milliohms.  With 8 amperes through it at a duty cycle of 30%, it would dissipate about 36 milliwatts, certainly nothing to get excited about.

But there's a problem...

If there's 13.5V across the coil and it has a resistance of 1.7 milliohms, then the current through it wouldn't be 8 amperes, it'd be about 7900 amperes. So, the question to this answer is:

Is the reactance and/or the skin depth of the coil high enough to do the limiting?

Comment: I've calcualted inductance from V/L=di/dt. Where V is 13.5V, di = 40%ripple in current, and dt is on time, when the current is flowing through the inductor to ground. This is for boost converter. Did I miss something?

Comment: This is the website where the calculations are from: http://www.simonbramble.co.uk/dc_dc_converter_design/boost_converter/boost_converter_design.htm

Comment: @GRTech I guess I'll have to do it Spehro's way.